# Bang! Calamity Janet and the High Noon Expansion

Tags: bang

In the Bang! expansion pack, there is a card known as "The Sermon" which reads as follows:

> **The Sermon:** BANG! cards cannot be used in player's turn

Seems straight-forward enough, until I realized that Calamity Janet can use Bang! cards as Missed! and Missed! cards as Bang!s.  So, my question is: if Calamity Janet is in play, can she use a Missed! card as a Bang!, since it technically isn't the actual Bang! card?

Comment: The way my play group deals with this is that she can't play them during her turn because she plays them as a bang which can't be played.

Comment: Relevant but not authoritative (unless the user "Alkan" is someone important) - http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/36169

Comment: @Rainbolt Yes, Alkan is very important: the designer of the game :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the creator of Bang! (Emiliano Sciarra) on [BoardGameGeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/36169):

> Actually, during the Sermon you cannot use Bang! cards during your turn only: it is allowed to use Bang! cards outside your turn. It follows that if you play a Duel, your opponent may answer with his Bang! while you can not, and so you will lose the Duel!
>   **As regards Calamity Janet, the general rule of thumb is that her Missed! cards are considered as if they were Bang! cards, so during the Sermon she cannot use Missed! cards as Bang! cards.**

Comment: And of course she could use Missed! as Missed!, but can she use Bang! as Mssed! (I would assume so).